# Expo Go with Google/Facebook OAuth - auth.expo.io login screen - "Not Found"

Tags: react-native, oauth, expo, google-oauth, expo-go

I am trying to set up google oauth in a react native, expo managed app.  **I am only having the following issue using my app within Expo Go** - when I create a build of the app, the oauth flow works perfectly.  But its hard to develop that way, and I need to be able to share a working app with non-dev team members via Expo Go.  I have set up the flow in what I think is the same as what the [expo go google auth documentation](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/authentication/#google) has described.  An overview

- Create a project in google console, and set up a new ClientID for web applications.  Set the authorized origins and redirect uri:

[image]

Where `myorg` is the name of the expo organizational account that owns the project, and `projectname` is the same value as `slug` in app.json.

- After setting this up, I get the client id, and client secret for this oauth login method.
- In my app code, I follow the instructions to use the `expo-auth-session` library for google:

```js
import * as WebBrowser from "expo-web-browser";
import * as Google from "expo-auth-session/providers/google";

WebBrowser.maybeCompleteAuthSession();

export const OAuthButtons: React.FC = () => {
  const [request, response, promptAsync] = Google.useAuthRequest({
    expoClientId: "clientId-from-google-console.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    iosClientId: "will set this up eventually",
    androidClientId: "will set this up eventually",
  });

  return; // markup for sign in buttons

}
```

So now in my app, when I click the google sign in button, I get the prompt to open the web browser correctly:

[image]

Clicking that correctly opens the expo web browser, but I see a "not found" message:

[image]

For more details, when I log the `request`, I get some pretty expected values

```
"{
  "url": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fauth.expo.io%2FMyProject&client_id=id-from-console.apps.googleusercontent.com&response_type=token&state=5xWG83SsoJ&scope=openid%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email",
  "responseType": "token",
  "clientId": "client-id-from-console.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  "redirectUri": "https://auth.expo.io/MyProject",
  "scopes": [
    "openid",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"
  ],
  "state": "5xWG83SsoJ",
  "extraParams": {},
  "codeChallengeMethod": "S256",
  "usePKCE": false
}"
```

The only values here that are a bit unexpected are the `redirectUri` and `redirect_uri`, which have a `/MyProject` appended to them, which is not exactly what I had put in my redirect uri in the google console.  How did that get appended there?  Might that be the problem?

As far as I can tell, I've set everything up as described.  What is it exactly that is "Not Found" here?  The oauth page for this particular expo application?  Where did I go wrong in my setup?

#### Edit - Same Problem with `Facebook.useAuthRequest`

I am having the same exact problem with the Facebook provider module as well.  Similar code:

```js
  const [facebookRequest, facebookResponse, facebookPromptAsync] =
    Facebook.useAuthRequest({
      clientId: "facebook_app_id",
      responseType: ResponseType.Code,
    });
```

I also tried the suggestion from the article [Use expo-auth-session with Facebook the Easiest Way on iOS/Android](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/use-expo-auth-session-with-facebook-the-most-easy-way-on-ios-android-1fd168deaf58) to add the `useProxy: true` property, but that makes no difference.

```js
  const [facebookRequest, facebookResponse, facebookPromptAsync] =
    Facebook.useAuthRequest(
      {
        clientId: "facebook_app_id",
        responseType: ResponseType.Code,
      },
      { useProxy: true }
    );
```

The facebook login also opens the expo browser to an empty page that says "Not found"

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have your `originalFullName` specify on your app.json? If not, try to add it e.g `originalFullName: "@your_username/your_app_name"`

And maybe this github issue can help you, https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/19891.

Comment: Wow this worked.  I did have `originalFullName` specified, but it was not in the format `@name/slug` - once I put it in that format, the in-app browser opens to the auth.expo.io proxy, which then forwards to google login.  Thank you!